# The Boggle Problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

An open question in mathematics that has yet to be resolved is as follows: given an $N\times N$ boggle grid, how many total simple (non-intersecting, in the sense of not returning to the same node twice) paths, including paths of length zero, are there?

Despite the seemingly simple nature of this question, the answers are only known up to $N=5$, and they are as follows:

$$1,64,10305,12029640,115066382913$$

Does anyone have any additional insight on this problem?

Comment: Only that these sort of enumeration problems tend to be, as a rule, tremendously complicated and seldom have straightforward answers; related questions are the number of polyominos of (up to) a given size and the number of lattice animals of (up to) a given size, and both questions are notoriously hard.

Comment: And the $3\times3$ case is related to phone unlocking patterns, a topic which had some discussion on math.se a year or two ago.

Comment: This question seems too vague to get a useful answer. Perhaps you are asking for references that have more information on this problem? That could have an answer...

Comment: This reminds me of a talk by D.E. Knuth's about the number of paths in an $N×N$ grid that visit each square once, starting at the lower-left corner and making only orthogonal moves. Knuth said at one point that an exact count for the $10×10$ case was probably out of reach. But then ten years later the problem had been solved, not merely by better computers but by development of better counting technique.